# Given classes with the same function but different implementation logic, how do I call a specific one based on a key w/o an `if...else` or `switch`?

Tags: typescript, class, oop

I have 10 classes that have the same function but different logic. How do I cleanly and DRY-ly call  these during runtime? The following implementation feels inefficient because it instantiates 10 classes but might only use one or two. I could also have a giant `if...else` or `switch` statement, but that feels incorrect as well.

What is the "correct" way to do this? Alternatively, is there a a term for this I can look up and learn on my own?

```
class MyClass1 {
    public getNum(): number {
        return 1;
    }
}

class MyClass2  {
    public getNum(): number {
        return 2;
    }
}

// 8 more classes of this nature


class Nums {
    myClasses: any = {}

    constructor () {
        this.myClasses['keyA'] = new MyClass1()
        this.myClasses['keyB'] = new MyClass2()
        // instantiate 8 remaining classes
    }

    protected getNums(key: string): number {
        return this.myClasses[key].getNum()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is necessarily a "correct" way to do this, so this question might be closed as opinion.  One way to do it is [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/W4bOON), where you keep an object full of class *constructors*, and then `Nums` only creates and uses instances when `getNums()` is called (and I made that public instead of `protected` to demonstrate it being used).  So how should we proceed here?  This feels more like a code review question and therefore not particularly well suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's hard to recommend how to refactor a contrived example. If that was all the code you had, then I'd do this: https://tsplay.dev/Nav12m. But if you need those to be classes with much more complex logic then that example won't exactly apply. So what's the actual goal, and what _exactly_ are you concerned about?

Comment: Both of those help. It appears as though creating a dict that stores all of the classes is the way to go. I was under the impression this would be possible without that dict, but both examples have it and does solve my underlying problem.

Thank you.

Comment: @jcalz Actually this would be off-topic on code review because it isn't real code from a project.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it be moved to codereview.stackoverflow.com, only saying that it's not really well-suited for here because it is taking working code and inviting opinions on a "better" way to do it.